# Unattended Upgrades email from address

Tags: server, email, gmail, unattended-upgrades, sendmail

I am ubuntu 19.04 and have found sSMTP no longer works properly and have switched over to msmtp and msmtp-mta for sendmail alias. I am in the process of getting unattended upgrades setup. It is currently setup and working properly, but I would like to get email notifications working properly. I currently have 3 different ubuntu servers all with notifications.

I own my own domain and have an email address setup that has permission for a gmail address to send from it. I have notifications@mydomain.com and mygmail@gmail.com has permission to send from it.

Doing a simple testing with msmtp allows me to send email and it will arrive as being from notifications@mydomain.com even though it is authenticating to mygmail@gmail.com.

The issue comes into place when running unattended upgrades. Even though the test msmtp works, unattended upgrades sends the email and it arrives as mygmail@gmail.com.

I would like it to be setup so the from address is notifications@mydomain.com and preferably the sender's name be the servers name, but I am having trouble getting that work.

I have tried setting the chfn on root and that reflects within passwd. I have also tried setting up an /etc/aliases file and specifying it within /etc/msmtprc, but I am not sure if I am setting that up properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks